# View linking to wrong content type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, view

I have a list that uses three different content types. Content type management is enabled for it.

Now, when I create my own view, and set the fields' property `LinkToItem` to `TRUE`, the links in the view all lead to the default display form, not the display form of the content type of the item the user clicked.

I have tried everything, but the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452757.aspx) is poor and incomplete, there is no code completion in the Designer, and I can't find a way to edit the links. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm using a built-in column that all lists inherit from the Item content type. It's the LinkTitle. It's a calculated field that automatically adds the correct content type in the querystring, so it solves my problem.